# react native check null,undefined,empty

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native, i am programmin my first project and i have a really simple question.

I have a Screen that shows the data of a product, the data are fetch from a url
Here is a sample of the fetch object

```
    {"id":"2-1","product_name":"sample product","price":"0.29","qty_step":"1","mm":"item","tax":"24.00","large_box_discount":8,"mpn":"2221","manufacturer_name":"company","weight":"0.027","ogkos_m3":"0.00011697","barcode":"002000100001","colors":["red","blue"],"sizes":null
}
```

The problem is when i try to render color and sizes.

```
{/*colors*/}
<View>
    if (data!=undefined && data.colors!=undefined && data.colors!=null)
    {
             data.colors.map( (item, index) => (
                <View style={styles.AvailabilityWrapper}>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            ))
    }
</View>

{/*sizes*/}
<View>
    if (data!=undefined && data.sizes!=undefined && data.sizes!=null && data.sizes!="")
    {
        data.sizes.map( (item, index) => (
            <View style={styles.AvailabilityWrapper}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
        ))
    }
</View>
```

**In case of sizes**
I get undefined is not a function but i have check if is undefined or null or empty

Is my if statement wrong ? What am i doing wrong ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: I have answered your question. Please check and let me know if you need any other help.. I AM HAPPY TO HELP YOU OUT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax:
`<View>some text</View>` renders plains text.

This syntax:
`<View>{ 4 > 3 ? "F" : "K" }</View>` evaluates whatever is in the braces.

You will want to write something like this instead.

```
<View>
  {(data?.sizes || []).map((item) => { ... })}
</View>
```

Btw, a more general pattern for conditional rendering looks like this

```
<View>
  {test
     ? <ComponentThatShouldOnlyBeRenderedWhenTestIsTruthy />
     : null}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The **MAP** function expects a ***return*** statement in order to display the contents(JSX) written inside that function. So add a return before your View tag.
2. Your if loop is promising however you could it write it better in this way. `if(data && data.size && data.size.length > 0)`. I would recommend this as it covers all cases.
3. RULE: You cannot use if loops inside your render function. A quick fix to this is given in the code below.

Check this code:

```
{/*colors*/}
<View>
  {
    data && 
    data.colors && 
    data.colors.length > 0 && 
    data.colors.map((item, index) => {
                return <View style={styles.AvailabilityWrapper}>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            })
  }
</View>

{/*sizes*/}
<View>
  {
    data && 
    data.sizes && 
    data.sizes.length > 0 && 
    data.sizes.map((item, index) => {
                return <View style={styles.AvailabilityWrapper}>
                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            })
  }
</View>
```